# Printing PDO results when using the IN() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

im trying out PDO for the first time with the below code.
I'm not printing any results when I am expecting some.

I have tested the query in phpmyadmin and I am using php version 5.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

$hostname = '###';
$username = '###';
$password = '###';

//  $ids=array(Pete, Julia); 
    $ids=array('Pete', 'Julia'); 
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=wizardlog", $username, $password); 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM wizardlog WHERE driver IN(:an_array)' ); 
    $stmt->bindParam('an_array',$ids); 
    $stmt->execute();


 print("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: "); 
 print("Return next row as an array indexed by column name\n"); 
 $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
 print_r($result); 
 print("\n"); 


// while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
// { echo 'results:'.$row['driver'].' '.$row['town']; } 

  ?> 

  <body>
  <html>
```

Comment: You can't do that. Placeholders can only be used for individual values, not lists.